# Can anyone explain ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

Can anyone explain ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick in TYPO3? I can't understand those tools.

I try hard to understand these tools

Comment: All the options, settings, operators and commands are listed and described here https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php

Comment: Are you asking about the arguments for Imagemagick or are you asking about how TYPO3 specifies its arguments? Your question is not clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TYPO3 uses UmageMagick or GraphicsMagick to do image computation outside the limits for webcalls. A web call results in an execution of PHP with limited resources (time and memory). To avoid this restrictions TYPO3 does a shell call to IM/GM for computations on images.

Image computation is done mostly in form of resizing, but in general you could do many more with the [GifBuilder](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/Gifbuilder/Gifbuilder/Index.html#gifbuilder).
Some examples can be seen in the InstallTool / AdminTool -> Environment -> Image Processing.
That's also the place where you check whether the configuration does work.